Conversion variable from 1 column to 6 with parameters
im working on the Google Data Analytics Capstone Project using my own path and i ended up having a large dataset 86k rows which look something like this
Date   loc   loc_type  variable   value
---------------------------------------
1      1       1         1         (num)
---------------------------------------
1      1       1         2         (num)
---------------------------------------
1      1       1         3         (num)
---------------------------------------
1      1       1         4         (num)
---------------------------------------
1      1       1         5         (num)
---------------------------------------
1      1       1         6         (num)
---------------------------------------
1      1       2         1         (num)
---------------------------------------
1      1       2         2         (num)
---------------------------------------
1      1       2         3         (num)
---------------------------------------
1      1       2         4         (num)
---------------------------------------
1      1       2         5         (num)
---------------------------------------
1      1       2         6         (num)
---------------------------------------
1      2       1         1         (num)
---------------------------------------
1      2       1         2         (num)
---------------------------------------

i have no clue where to start but i want something like this
Date   loc   loc_type  var1   var2   var3   var4   var 5   var6
------------------------------------------------------------------
1        1      1     (num)   (num)  (num)  (num)  (num)   (num)
------------------------------------------------------------------
1        1      2     (num)   (num)  (num)  (num)  (num)   (num)
------------------------------------------------------------------
1        2      1     (num)   (num)  (num)  (num)  (num)   (num)
------------------------------------------------------------------
1        2      2     (num)   (num)  (num)  (num)  (num)   (num)
------------------------------------------------------------------
1        3      1     (num)   (num)  (num)  (num)  (num)   (num)
------------------------------------------------------------------
1        3      2     (num)   (num)  (num)  (num)  (num)   (num)
------------------------------------------------------------------
2        1      1     (num)   (num)  (num)  (num)  (num)   (num)
------------------------------------------------------------------


Have you tried a pivottable, with the first three fields as row headers, the fourth as column header, and the minimum of the last field as value? (minimum or maximum makes no difference, assuming you only have one occurrence of each)

i tried to create different datasets for each variable and then add them up but doesnt work cause loc and loc type are not constant values.. some variables are tracked only by centrain loc ...

pivot table works but i cant use things like scatter plots to check variable dependencies... i used average in my pivot table to check average yearly /montly values etc

in R terms this can be very simply done using tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = variable, names_prefix = "var", values_from = value)

i knew it was something simple but didnt know how to do it... thx bro.. it worked

using tidyr in r:
# data mockup
df <- data.frame(Date = 1,
                 loc = rep(1:6, each = 12),
                 loc_type = rep(1:2, each = 6),
                 variable = 1:6,
                 value = 1:72)                 

df |> tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = variable, names_prefix = "var", values_from = value)

yields:
    Date   loc loc_type  var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6
   <dbl> <int>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     1     1        1     1     2     3     4     5     6
 2     1     1        2     7     8     9    10    11    12
 3     1     2        1    13    14    15    16    17    18
 4     1     2        2    19    20    21    22    23    24
 5     1     3        1    25    26    27    28    29    30
 6     1     3        2    31    32    33    34    35    36
 7     1     4        1    37    38    39    40    41    42
 8     1     4        2    43    44    45    46    47    48
 9     1     5        1    49    50    51    52    53    54
10     1     5        2    55    56    57    58    59    60
11     1     6        1    61    62    63    64    65    66
12     1     6        2    67    68    69    70    71    72


@MarinosKaitis glad to hear it - if you're happy with the result please click the "tick" next to the answer to mark is as accepted.
